# How to get this bar in Safari on iOS 6?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, ios6

There's this bar that appears at the top, with an app's icon and a link to it on the App Store. I've seen it on several sites, and I think this is part of iOS 6. Any idea on how to get it to show?

[image: The bar at the top]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is "smart banner" appeared in iOS6, you can check for example [this post](http://firebrand-media.com/blog/article/creating_smart_app_banners_for_ios_6) or [page in Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) to see how to create them

Basically all you need to do is to add a `<meta>` tag to your page with specific format:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=YOUR_APP_ID">
```